# External ID not found

Tags: odoo

Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
r = d[key]

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/tools/func.py", line 71, in wrapper
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in **getitem**
a = self.d[obj]

KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x7f5794273a60>, 'account.account_invoices_without_payment')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 2121, in report_download

```
response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter=converter, context=context)
```

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/http.py", line 532, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 2056, in report_routes

```
pdf = report.with_context(context)._render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data)[0]
```

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/addons/account/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 41, in _render_qweb_pdf

```
invoice_reports = (self.env.ref('account.account_invoices_without_payment'), self.env.ref('account.account_invoices'))
```

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/api.py", line 511, in ref
return self['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_object(xml_id, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1944, in xmlid_to_object

```
t = self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(xmlid, raise_if_not_found)
```

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1928, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id

```
return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
```

File "", line 2, in xmlid_lookup

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup
value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1921, in xmlid_lookup

```
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
```

ValueError: External ID not found in the system:

account.account_invoices_without_payment

The error occurs when I tried to print an invoice. It happens even if I choose an empty print template. Any help?Thanks.

Comment: You or someone probably deleted that report? Just update `account` app and it should be there again.

Comment: This kind of error will raise when model name wrongly given. Kindly check it py and security file.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should be check table *ir_model_data* with *name=account.account_invoices_without_payment*. If you can find, you must update module account. If you can't find, you can be insert new record table *ir_model_data* with *name* and *res_id* = *id view account_invoices_without_payment in ir_ui_view*.

May be help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade the module account and make sure that the db using correctly. You can give db-filter to choose the db correctly

Answer (score 0):

After checking in the settings-> external id. I find that somehow this external id got deleted for unknown reason. I opened an new database and compared and find that this is the case then I create a new eternal id according to the new db's value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).